# Python get cookies on request

Tags: python, cookies

I've seen many topics asking to get cookies after a request has been made but I want the cookies Python sends out to a website. I have a site (`site.com`) where if you go to they give you an `Authorization` cookie. This is not in the response cookies but it's in the request cookies on Firefox Network activity. I'm wondering, is it posible to get the cookies sent with a request to a site?

I've tried:

```py
import requests

session = requests.Session()
session.get("site.com")
print(session.cookies.get_dict())
```

But that didn't give me the request cookies

Comment: Have you tried inspecting the headers?

Answer (score 1):

I do this and it does work.

```
>>> import requests
>>> session = requests.Session()
>>> print(session.cookies.get_dict())
{}
>>> response = session.get('http://google.com')
>>> print(session.cookies.get_dict())
{'PREF': 'ID=5514c728c9215a9a:FF=0:TM=1406958091:LM=1406958091:S=KfAG0U9jYhrB0XNf', 'NID': '67=TVMYiq2wLMNvJi5SiaONeIQVNqxSc2RAwVrCnuYgTQYAHIZAGESHHPL0xsyM9EMpluLDQgaj3db_V37NjvshV-eoQdA8u43M8UwHMqZdL-S2gjho8j0-Fe1XuH5wYr9v'}
```

Thanks

Comment: Printed nothing both times